# Construct a function satisfying a convexity type inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am trying to construct a test function $f$ such that
$f''+\frac{d-1}{r}f'\geq C f$
where $0\leq f\leq 1$, $f=0$ for $r\leq 1$ and $f=1$ for $r\geq 2$, $C>0$ and $d\geq 3.$

My initial guess was to take $f$ as a log function but then it is not differentiable at the endpoints $r=1$ and $r=2.$ I have tried to interpolate using a polynomial at the endpoints but then I loose the desired convexity condition.

Any ideas to construct such a test function will be greatly appreciated!